Azure VDI - pooled desktop
I have installed Azure VDI with pooled (One Virtual Host) with five users and all are working fine. But these five users get the same IP address which is the same Host IP address. Is there is any way to make each user get a separate IP Address without moving each of them to use personal desktop?
Need solution for separate IP Address without moving each of them to use personal desktop
